# How to remove this bathroom shelf?

Tags: bathroom, shelf

I'm trying to remove the shelf in the bathroom, which aside from two screws, appears to be affixed with some cement around the wall? Any advice on how to remove it without damaging the tiles?

There will be a cabinet that will go in place of this shelf, so it will hide any damage.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously remove the screws first then:

If it's caulk or something soft, cut away with a knife.

If it's construction adhesive, epoxy, or anything hard here are some things you could try depending on your comfort with them:

- a wire saw.  Pull the wire across the joint but away from the wall, so scratching the tiles may be limited to the area right behind this shelf.
- A hammer and chisel.  An old wood chisel, that you will ruin this way, or a flat screwdriver.   Hammer **gently** into the joint.  You could easily smash the tiles this way, you don't want to do that.  The objective with this approach is that if the glue joint is poor, you will dislodge it.  If that fails, stop.  You are not trying to smash it away bit by bit.
- A an open ended (pistol style) hack saw might work, although I think the wire saw will be more effective and less likely to scratch surrounding tiles.
- A rotary tool with a grinding wheel is how I've seen grout specialists remove old grout.  But your shelf is fairly thick (top to bottom) and if it's glued all the way through, a grinding wheel won't reach.
- A reciprocating saw .... I'm including that just because I think it's a bad idea, more likely to bounce around and scratch the tile than to help especially if there is glue all the way down the back of the shelf.  But you could try it carefully to see if I'm wrong.
- A hammer and chisel (part two) .... this time a cold chisel or screwdriver, applied to the shelf itself to smash it away in pieces until there is nothing left but the back wall of it.   This will give you better angles and leverage to go back to the top of the list and try again.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will definitely start with the screws, which is indeed obvious.

The material looks and feels the same way as the one used between tiles, I'd say caulk?

And yes, I'll be installing a bathroom cabinet in place of this shelf.

Comment: Yes, it appears that is grout between the tiles and also in the joint at the shelf.  A oscillating tool might help with removal of the grout.

Comment: I would start with fishing line...a garrote if you will.   That would do the least harm and hopefully cut right through the caulk.

Comment: @SteveWellens per OP comments it's not caulk, so actual (nylon) fishing line is probably not going to work but I agree ... that would be a good place to start because if it *does* work it will do least harm.

Comment: @jay613, Thanks for such a detailed answer (I saw that you updated it)!
I will definitely try something from these.
What about a dental floss? It's nylon too (I don't have the fishing line)

Comment: Floss?   We don't know what the adhesive is. From your comments I'm assuming it's grout or tile adhesive or epoxy or something like that. You want something that will cut through that but won't scratch the tile behind it. That probably doesn't exist. I don't think dental floss is the right compromise. I don't think a reciprocating saw is either. I think you should go for something in between.

Comment: Instead of the fishing line, you can use a cable saw, like is often used for PVC pipes in spaces tough to reach with a bladed saw.

Comment: @jay613, thanks a lot for your advice! I've tried the method with screwdriver and a hammer and it worked like magic :-)
If someone can choose the answer, please do so

Answer (score 0):

That shelf is most likely installed between tiles.  That is, the tiles above and below the shelf provide the support. This is especially critical at the corner.

Your pics are actually too close.  The tell-tale factor is the corner.

Removing the shelf can leave a gap in the tiles.  This is one of those times where there is no way to remove something without additional work needed after. What work is unknown until the shelf is removed.
Can you remove it without damaging the tile?  Maybe, maybe not, this is a situation where surgical removal is needed, but there is no guarantee there will not be damage.

Remove the screws. Use a rubber hammer and rap down on the top of the shelf. Then try under, hitting up.  (Wear all the proper safety protection).  It may help having someone hold the shelf while you hit it, so it doesn't fall and cause more damage. There are no "tricks" that I know of.

I have removed corner shelves. Filled the gap with sanded grout and sealed the grout.  This still left an ugly scar.  I covered the scar with a stainless metal shelf that looked more modern.  Sealing the edges around the new shelf as well.  This was acceptable to the homeowner, but may not be what you are after.

Bottom line here is, it looks as if you will need to find a new suitable shelf or retile that entire area while maintaining the waterproof envelope.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I am uploading some more photos a bit further away to show that it's actually and thankfully not a corner shelf.

Comment: Updated the original post

Comment: Eliminate all but the top 2 pics.  Those are all that are needed.  I now believe that the shelf may not be between tiles.  Still take it down and then you will know what you have to deal with.  The 2 holes above the shelf, indicate that there was another shelf as well.

Comment: There was a simple mirror above which was affixed using four screws (obviously) and metallic holders.. I have removed the mirror myself, which was relatively easy.
Removed pictures as well.

Comment: If you are going to add a cabinet, knock out the shelf and cover the scar.  I originally thought it was in a shower area.